# PIN lock implementation

Tags: android, onresume

I'm building an app which requires some security. Everytime user quit the application with the **Home** button, or when he locks the phone and unlocks it, a **PIN** code is prompted.

To add this feature, I need a callback fired when these situations happen. I tried to use `onResume` in my activities, but this method is also called while navigating between activities. I have also tried to implement an Application subclass, but there is no `onResume` override.

What is my best option?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so trivial task to be honest. I've did it twice, and ended both times in: 
- keeping state of app (locked, unlocked) 
- using package manager to check if app is on top (==not set to background) 
- calling functions that are checking for app locking onResume, onPause, onDestroy 
- having timer that locks the app after some period of inactivity

My first implementation was based on activity with pin verification, second one - on fragments, and I'd suggest using fragments as